# How to add foreign key using fluent API when only model1 has reference to other model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

how can I add a foreign key using fluent api?

eg.

model1

id, name, model2.id

model2

id, name

I've read about [HasOne Method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasone-method) for building one to one relationship but this example shows the model1 only have reference to model2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a demo below which model1 is `Employee` and model2 is `Department`, `Employee` has a reference to `Department`

models:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

dcContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Department)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Employee>(e => e.DepartmentId);

    }
```

result:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Employees",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                DepartmentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Employees", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Employees_Department_DepartmentId",
                    column: x => x.DepartmentId,
                    principalTable: "Department",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            })
```